# How can I rotate a div with respect to a canvas that rotates on mousedrag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a canvas tube1Ctx and a div with id sineWave. The canvas is rotated on mouse drag using pure Javascript. Now I need to rotate the div at the same time with respect to the canvas (same angular displacement). When I have tried with below code the transform style not gets updated while drag rotate the canvas. Could anybody please help me to solve?

```
function tubeRotate(e){
    
    if (moveFlag2){
    
    tube1XPos = e.clientX - tube1Canvas.offsetLeft;
    tube1YPos = e.clientY - tube1Canvas.offsetTop;  
    
        
    rotate = tube1XPos-((e.clientX-tube1Canvas.offsetLeft));    
    rotate = (Math.atan(240/rotate))* Math.PI / 180;
    tube1Ctx.clearRect(240,10,tube1Canvas.width,tube1Canvas.height);    
    tube1Ctx.translate(275, 10);
    tube1Ctx.rotate(rotate);    
    tube1Ctx.translate(-275,-10 );  
    tube1Ctx.drawImage(tube1Img,240 , 10 , 46 , 235 );
    

        var angle=rotate;

    document.getElementById("sineWave").style.MozTransformOrigin='0% 0%';
    document.getElementById("sineWave").style.MozTransform =  'rotate('+angle+'rad)';
    
    document.getElementById("sineWave").style.webkitTransformOrigin='0% 0%';
    document.getElementById("sineWave").style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+angle+'rad)';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing quote

document.getElementById("sineWave).style.MozTransformOrigin='0% 0%';

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake while i am copying the code to here, Its there in my working copy.